# What is the best solution to solve this types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

My example: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-clarke-rex8l `src/index.ts`

```
  enum EndpointEnum {
    summary,
    detailed
  }

  type Summary = string;
  type Detailed = number;

  const getData = <T>() => {
    return [] as T[];
  };

  const format = (format: Summary[]) => [];

  const main = <T>(someEnum: EndpointEnum) => {
    const data = getData<T>();

    if (someEnum === EndpointEnum.summary) {
      return format(data);
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  };

  main<Summary>(EndpointEnum.summary);
  main<Detailed>(EndpointEnum.detailed);
```

I am pretty new to TypeScript.

You can see the `format` function only accepts `String[]` but I am using a generic type. I don't really know how to solve it in an elegant way.

The two things I can think of is to do

```
const main = <T extends Summary | Detailed>(someEnum: EndpointEnum) => {
```

and then typecast `format(data as Summary[]);`

or

do some ugly type guards which would be effectively type casting too.

Is there a way of doing it in a clean way?

Comment: Post the relevant code **in the question itself**. Not as a link to an external page.

Comment: What's the question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How does `getData()` know what type to return?  What type does `format()` return?  Your code doesn't seem to be a [mcve] so it's hard to know how to answer this.  My guess is that if you don't use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) type you will have to use something like [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (not "casting", which is a misleading term here) to tell the compiler what you're doing.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One way you can go about achieving this is to make the `format` function generic, itself, and force its return to be `Summary[]`.

```
enum EndpointEnum {
    summary,
    detailed
}

type Summary = string;
type Detailed = number;

const getData = <T>(): T[] => {
    return [];
};

const format = <T>(format: T[]): Summary[] => [];

const main = <T>(someEnum: EndpointEnum) => {
    const data = getData<T>();

    if (someEnum === EndpointEnum.summary) {
        return format(data);
    } else {
        return data;
    }
};

main<Summary>(EndpointEnum.summary);
main<Detailed>(EndpointEnum.detailed);
```

It may not make sense as a function signature to do it that way, but it does give you some implementation flexibility later on.

For example, you could have `format` call other, more specific, formatting functions internally and still return a `Summary[]` in the end.

Hopefully, that gets you closer to what you were looking for.  Otherwise, as you said, you'll need to do some `extends` or type casting to achieve the needed result.